# Is it ok to store all integers as Strings instead of byte[] in hbase?

Tags: hbase

I am trying out some hbase code. I realised that when I insert data through hbase shell using put command, then everything (both numeric and string) is put as string:

```
hbase(main):001:0> create 'employee', {NAME => 'f'}
hbase(main):003:0> put 'employee', 'ganesh','f:age',30
hbase(main):004:0> put 'employee', 'ganesh','f:desg','mngr'
hbase(main):005:0> scan 'employee'
ROW                   COLUMN+CELL
ganesh               column=f:age, timestamp=1467926618738, value=30
ganesh               column=f:desg, timestamp=1467926639557, value=mngr
```

However when I put data using Java API, non-string stuff gets serialized as `byte[]`:

```
Cluster lNodes = new Cluster();
lNodes.add("digitate-VirtualBox:8090");
Client lClient= new Client(lNodes);
RemoteHTable remoteht = new RemoteHTable(lClient, "employee");

Put lPut = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("mahesh"));
lPut.add(Bytes.toBytes("f"), Bytes.toBytes("age"), Bytes.toBytes(25));
lPut.add(Bytes.toBytes("f"), Bytes.toBytes("desg"), Bytes.toBytes("dev"));
remoteht.put(lPut);
```

Scan in hbase shell shows `age` `25` of `mahesh` is stored as `\x00\x00\x00\x19`:

```
hbase(main):006:0> scan 'employee'
ROW                   COLUMN+CELL
ganesh               column=f:age, timestamp=1467926618738, value=30
ganesh               column=f:desg, timestamp=1467926639557, value=mngr
mahesh               column=f:age, timestamp=1467926707712, value=\x00\x00\x00\x19
mahesh               column=f:desg, timestamp=1467926707712, value=dev
```

1. Considering I will be storing only numeric and string data in hbase, what benefits it does provide to store numeric data as `byte[]` (as in case of above) or as string:

   ```
   lPut.add(Bytes.toBytes("f"), Bytes.toBytes("age"), Bytes.toBytes("25"));  //instead of toBytes(25)
   ```
2. Also why strings are stored as is and are not serialized to `byte[]` even when put using Java API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to read more about hbase. Hbase stores everything as byte[]. You see shell output converted to string when you scan table. And sometimes non-string data like integers can not converted properly. But this is just hbase shell trying to be human-readable, internally everything is byte[]. 
So

1- If you store integers, you need to store them as integer so they always use 4 bytes, if you store them as string they use 1 byte per length, maybe 2 bytes.

2- Strings are converted to byte[] as i said above, so this is just shell makes you think that way.

Comment: ohhh great I got it...I was unnecessarily thinking its storing string as is. Also `\x00\x00\x00\x19=(11001)bin=(25)dec` It seems proper `byte[]` form of 25, unless there is nothing more involved in conversion of `int` to `byte[]`.